# I changed the name of the WPF form and now it refuses to launch the application

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

This is probably a very simple fix.

1. I clicked the form in the Solution Explorer.
2. Pressed F2 to rename it. Renamed it "MyForm.xaml". Pressed enter.
3. Tried launching the application but I get this error:

> Cannot locate resource 'window1.xaml'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In App.xaml, there will be a `StartupUri="Window1.xaml"`. Change this to `StartupUri="MyForm.xaml"`.